# Is there any such thing as a change in acceleration (ex: 3 m/s/s/s)?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, jerk

If there exists something like that, then in $distance/time/time/time$, how is it expressed?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136880/2451 and links therein.

Comment: In fact, it is not only possible, it is *necessarily* the case.  That is to say, uniform acceleration is not physically realizable.

Answer (score 12):

http://wordpress.mrreid.org/2013/12/11/jerk-jounce-snap-crackle-and-pop/

Speaking derivatives to time:

- First **position** $x$,
- then **velocity** $v=x'=\frac{dx}{dt}$,
- then **acceleration** $a=x''=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$,
- then **jerk** $x'''=\frac{d^3x}{dt^3}$,
- then **jounce/snap** $x''''=\frac{d^4x}{dt^4}$,
- then **crackle** $x'''''=\frac{d^5x}{dt^5}$,
- then **pop** $x''''''=\frac{d^6x}{dt^6}$,
- ...

Comment: _Formally_, the fourth-derivitive of position is the [**jounce**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce), however, [someone published a paper using **snap**](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0309109.pdf) (see also the footnote on page 4). On a less serious note, when multiplied by mass, you get, respectively: [_kilogram-meter_](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32096/what-exactly-is-a-kilogram-meter) ($m\cdot x$), **momentum** ($m\cdot v$), **force** ($m\cdot a$), **yank** ($m\cdot jerk$), **tug** ($m\cdot snap$), **snatch** ($m\cdot crackle$), **shake** ($m\cdot pop$).

Comment: In valvetrain design engineering areas of linear snap (constant pop) are used as design limits for valve lift profiles.

Comment: d4x/dt4, d5x,/dt5, d6x/dt6, Rice Crispies!

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Rate of change of acceleration is called jerk. Yes its dimensional formula is $[M^0, L^1, T^{-3}]$. Similarly one could also define higher time derivatives of acceleration if required for a particular problem.

Comment: There is a name for the further derivatives of acceleration too, i believe jounce is the second derivative of a, though after that its not a consensus among physicists

Answer (score 4):

Yes. usually we name them **$a'$** . and there can be even a speed of my **$a'$** that I can call that **$a''$** and it goes on like that.

it is only used it real life calculation that the calculation should be very precise like rocket science.

and the equation of displacement (with a constant $a'$) will be :

$$x =\frac16 a't^3 + \frac12 a_0t^2 + v_0t+x_0$$

(EDIT: also should mention sometimes they put a little dot on the a too instead of apostrophe )

Comment: You might want to add that the equation holds only for constant rate of change of acceleration.

Comment: @user40330 yes good point.

Comment: Regarding the edit - yep, $\dot{b}$ indicates the change in a quantity, $b$, with respect to time: $\frac{db}{dt}$.

Comment: @HDE226868 thanks. I remember one my professors mentioned that you use apostrophe (and he always used this method) to mention the second acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

An actual example in which there is a non-zero change in acceleration, that is, jerk, occurs is a spring. A spring's motion is described by a sinusoidal function. The derivative of a sinusoidal function is just another sinusoidal function. As a result, you can differentiate such a function infinitely many times, and will never have a derivative that's 0/a constant. So not only is there there a non-zero jerk in the motion of a spring, every single derivative of position is non-zero.