# Why not consider rate of change of acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, jerk

Why do we not consider rate of change of acceleration in the study of linear motion?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136880/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we do need to consider the rate of change of acceleration - sufficiently often for it to have been given a name. The rate of change of acceleration is called [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)). Limiting the magnitude of jerk is an important consideration in the real world design of railway tracks, elevators and roller coasters.

The initial kinematics problems that you encounter in a physics course tend to focus on motion with constant acceleration for the sake of simplicity, so as not to confuse the student with too many new concepts at once.

Comment: I assume it stops there, that the rate of change of jerk is of no interest.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Not_Einstein Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth,_fifth,_and_sixth_derivatives_of_position

Comment: That's funny. I thought I was being a bit frivolous by even asking.