# Object moving with 2 linear accelerations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, acceleration

Say I have an object moving with an acceleration of 5 m/s$^2$. At a certain point X, due to some forces, the acceleration of the object changes from 5 m/s$^2$ to 2 m/s$^2$.

Would this change in acceleration be called deceleration? Or do we have other terminology to model this change in acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

It is still accelerating, albeit with a lesser magnitude. The derivative of acceleration is called Jerk (See [Physical intuition for higher order derivatives](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45517/392)). So at point *B* it is accelerating with negative jerk.