# Position, velocity, acceleration, jolt, and

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, differentiation, jerk

I am familiar with the fact that $\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}}=v$, $\displaystyle{\frac{dv}{dt} =a}$, and $\displaystyle{\frac{da}{dt}=J}$ where $J$ denotes the 'jolt', or jerk. Are further derivatives of position named, or is that basically as far as it goes, insofar as special names are concerned? Is there a name for the 4th derivative of position w.r.t time, for example?

Analogous to that question, we have that $\displaystyle{p=mv}$, $\displaystyle{F=ma}$, and $\displaystyle{Y=mJ}$, where $Y$ is the "yank." (I just found out about the 3rd derivative names today, which is the primary motivation for this question.)

$Mx$, mass times position, seems kind of meaningless and arbitrary, but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: They're called [snap, crackle, and pop](http://wordpress.mrreid.org/2013/12/11/jerk-jounce-snap-crackle-and-pop/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physical intuition for higher order derivatives](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45517/)

Comment: Yup thanks these comments were what I was looking for. Sorry, I hadn't found that question prior