# Why do the derivative of the acceleration (and subsequent derivatives) not play a significant role in physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, differentiation, jerk

During high-school and college I modeled all dynamic mechanical systems with displacement, velocity and acceleration. This was more than enough to address the systems and determine their behavior in the time domain for a certain external stimulation.

However, some part of my intuition keeps on telling me that further derivation past the second order of the displacement should also play a role, that is, the derivative of the acceleration should also be important when talking about dynamic systems.

For example, I feel completely different when accelerating smoothly but steadily harder (I get gradually pressed into my seat, as the derivative of the acceleration is small), compared to when I brake very hard (I go from no acceleration to full acceleration). ([See this question for other examples](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45517/132242)).

I know this is a weird question, but somehow I fail to reason about it and none of my text-books even mentions deriving the acceleration.

Comment: Hi Andres. This has already been discussed in several other questions. I've linked what I think is a good discussion, but follow the link in that question for yet more info. See also [Why are differential equations for fields in physics of order two?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/why-are-differential-equations-for-fields-in-physics-of-order-two).

Comment: @JohnRennie Indeed, this is replicated, sorry about that. I didn't know the derivative of acceleration is called `jerk` in English, and so failed during my google search. ¿Shall I delete my question then?¿Or could you close it please? Sorry again

Comment: It's up to you whether you want to delete the question. It does no harm to leave a few duplicates around as it makes it easier for people to search the site.

Comment: @JohnRennie Ok. I will leave it here then. Thank you very much :)