# Generalisations of AdS/CFT with string theory on both sides

Tags: string-theory, research-level, ads-cft, holographic-principle, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

From my previous [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/classical-theories-and-ads-cft), I found out from the comments that there are various generalisations of [AdS/CFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=AdS/CFT_correspondence&oldid=564493454) with different things replacing     the CFT on the RHS; such as [AdS/CMT](http://enwp.org/AdS_CMT), [AdS/QCD](http://enwp.org/AdS_QCD),  and also with the AdS replaced on the LHS, like Kerr/CFT a hydrodynamic dual, etc.

I am thus led to ask, "***Is there a generalisation of AdS/CFT with string theories on both sides?***"

I can think of at least 1 example of a/n (holographic?) equivalence between a $D$ - dimensional string theory and a $D+1$ - dimensional string theory, T-Duality.    E.g. the Type I String Theory and the  Type I' String Theory, etc.

n

Comment: Why do you say that T-duality is holographic?

Comment: @Matthew: It was meant to be a questionmark, i.e. "holographic?", since a side question was whether there any holographic cases of T-duality.

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples of such phenomena if strings are topological on both sides. It was discovered by Gopakumar and Vafa in the paper [On the Gauge Theory/Geometry Correspondence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9811131v1.pdf) as the duality between topological A-models on deformed and resolved conifolds.

There exists a generalization of this duality to more general manifolds. Look, for example, at the paper by Gomis and Okuda [D-branes as a Bubbling Calabi-Yau](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3080).