# An Integral from Feynman & Hibbs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, path-integral, integration

In Appendix "Some Useful Definite Integrals" of Feynman & Hibbs *"Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals"*  they use some integral formulas<sup>(1)</sup> that I'm struggling to derive, and mathematica can't do them either. In particular
\begin{equation}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\int_0^T \exp \left\{\frac{i a}{T-\tau}\right.  \left.+\frac{i b}{\tau}\right\} \frac{d \tau}{\left[\sqrt{(T-\tau) \tau}\right]^3}
=\sqrt{\frac{i \pi}{T^3}} \frac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a b}} \exp \left\{\frac{i}{T}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2\right\}
\tag{A-5}\label{A-5}
\end{equation}

for $a, b$ real and positive.

I have no idea how to do this as it is unlike any integral I've seen before. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

<sup>(1)
Page 357 in 1965 Edition, Equation \eqref{A-5} in page 359 of emended 2010 Edition.</sup>

Comment: Hint: substitute $\tau=T\sin^2\theta,\,x=\tan\theta$, write a $1+x^{-2}$ factor in the integrand in the form $A\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}x^{-2}\right)+B$ to split the integral, then use [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) with $u=x-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}x^{-1}$.

Comment: That's great, thanks!