# Integral from Feynman & Hibbs Appendix - solvable with Cauchy principal value

Tags: homework-and-exercises, path-integral, integration

In Appendix "Some Useful Definite Integrals" of Feynman & Hibbs "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals" they use some integral formulas that I'm struggling to derive. The integral is:

[image]

I've seen a question to solve an [almost similar integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742718/an-integral-from-feynman-hibbs), but the guy just gave a hint, and I still can't solve it. I know that is possible to get the solution of the "almost similar integral" just taking the partial derivative of my equation with respect
to $a$. So finding the result of the other integral is easy when we know the answer of this one, but how to solve this integral? I would appreciate some help.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with physics.

Comment: Don't use images for Math (or text). Use MathJax instead.

Comment: Did you try using the hint provided in the comments to the linked question?

Comment: Help on using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  Please not that posting images of text or mathematics is strongly discouraged on Physics SE (and several other science orientated sites on SE).